# System/Integration Testing with DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I would like to run system/integration tests in Azure DevOps.

I have a Visual Studio "test" solution

- Test

That includes three projects, that are normally being deployed (using Azure DevOps) as separate application/services.

- Change Listener and Transform Service
- Target Database Persistence Service
- Ancillary Tasks Service

Each of these projects comes from a solution in a separate Azure DevOps repo.

The "test" solution does the necessary inversion of control and performs the system testing.

However, this set-up only works on my laptop.

I'd like to move these system tests into Azure DevOps, but I'm not sure how to have one solution in an AZD Test Solution. Can anyone help me?